# Scons - build order of Fortran files

Tags: build, module, fortran, scons

Building modules in Fortran needs to be done in a specific order, e.g. if a file `A.f` needs module defined in `B.f`, then `B.f` needs to be **compiled** first. How can I impose such build order in Scons? If I provide it with a list of source files, it arranges them alphabetically (so `A.f` is compiled before `B.f`). I read about `Requires()` and `Depends()` functions, but wasn't able to get them to work for me.

I would be happy with just listing source files in order I need them compiled (so disabling reshuffling them in alphabetical order), but any other method would be welcomed as well.

As per Kyle's request, here's my Sconscript and a build log:

```
# Main program building script

Import('env')

PROGRAM = 'main.exe'

SRC_PREFIX = './src/'

SRC = [ 'array_1D_module.f', 
            'array_2D_module.f', 
            'array_3D_module.f', 
            'thomas_algorithm_module.f',
            'histogram_module.f',
            'histogram_computer_module.f',
            'density_parameters_module.f',
            'diffusion3D_aos_z_sub_solver_module.f',
            'diffusion3D_aos_y_sub_solver_module.f',
            'diffusion3D_aos_x_sub_solver_module.f',
            'diffusion3D_aos_solver_module.f',
            'nonlinear_diffusion_utilities_module.f',
            'nonlinear_diffusion_parameters_module.f',
            'derivative_magnitude_computer_module.f',
            'nonlinear_diffusion_module.f',
            'main_module.f',
            'main.f' ]

# Attach prefix to each source file
for i in range( len(SRC) ) :
    SRC[i] = SRC_PREFIX + SRC[i]


env.Program(target = PROGRAM, source = SRC)
```

This produced:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
ifort -o src/array_1D_module.o -c src/array_1D_module.f
ifort -o src/array_2D_module.o -c src/array_2D_module.f
ifort -o src/array_3D_module.o -c src/array_3D_module.f
ifort -o src/density_parameters_module.o -c src/density_parameters_module.f
ifort -o src/derivative_magnitude_computer_module.o -c src/derivative_magnitude_computer_module.f
ifort -o src/diffusion3D_aos_solver_module.o -c src/diffusion3D_aos_solver_module.f
src/diffusion3D_aos_solver_module.f(7): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [DIFFUSION3D_AOS_Z_SUB_SOLVER_MODULE]
    use diffusion3D_aos_z_sub_solver_module, only :
------------^
```

So `density_parameters_module.f` was compiled before `thomas_algorithm_module.f`, even though it comes after it in my list.

Comment: [Looks to me](http://www.scons.org/doc/2.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x474.html) that you need to define the list in the appropriate order and Scons will do the rest. IDK for sure, as I do not use Scons.

Comment: @KyleKanos - as I said, scons reshuffles your list to alphabetic order. My build logs confirm it, and so does the example you provided.

Comment: I just downloaded and tested it just now. I created `bee.f90`, `ae.f90`, and `print_a_lot.f90` with the last depending on `ae` and `ae` depending on `bee`. The list was `Program('program', ['bee.f90', 'ae.f90', 'print_a_lot.f90'])`. Typing `scons` in terminal built it just fine for me, no reversal of the order.

Comment: I also changed my list to `Program(['print_a_lot.f90', 'bee.f90', 'ae.f90'])` and was also able to compile this correctly. Perhaps you could post your `SConstruct` file?

Comment: @Kyle - edited as requested

Comment: scons does not build sequentially: it runs compilations in parallel.  If there is a dependency, you need to add it into either the SConstruct or SConscript file.  http://www.scons.org/doc/0.96.1/HTML/scons-user/x959.html

Comment: @cup - it's exactly specifying dependencies in Fortran that I wasn't able to figure out how to do correctly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is your program (as suggested) using modules? There's a couple of gotchas there:

1. FORTRANMODDIR needs defining: See http://scons.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=1272&dsMessageId=82725 for a discussion on that.
2. I found that having source files containing a mixture of module definitions and source code caused a certain amount of confusion.

Comment: When I copied the OP's SConstruct file for my set of `.f90` files, I too received a failure. However, adding in the `FORTRANMODDIR` as suggested in the linked discussion allowed `scons` to compile in the correct order. Hopefully the same will work for the OP.

Comment: Wiiii, FORTRANMODDIR did the trick! Thank you, Tom. And yep, I was using modules and didn't mix them with non-modules code inside same file.